# How do I remove blank in python 3

Tags: python, space, sentence

I have the following code

```
nsum = 1+3+4

print("your total Calorie count is",nsum,".")
```

When I run the scrip using python 3.6

it prints out `your total Calorie count is 8 .`

But I want to print this sentence without the blank space after the `nsum`.
like this:

```
your total Calorie count is 8.
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should look at using `format()` for string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

```
nsum = 1+3+4

print("your total Calorie count is %d." % nsum)
```

See [this page](https://pyformat.info/) for more information about formatting.